# Magento 2 Error - Model collection resource name is not defined

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm going through Magento 2 tutorials and I'm having trouble getting a collection from my custom model's factory after calling the create() method. It throws an error saying the "Model collection resource name is not defined". I've already cleared /var/generation and recompiled the di.

Company/Module/Model/Vendor.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
    protected function _constructor() {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Resource\Vendor');
    }
}
```

Company/Module/Model/Resource/Vendor.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\Resource;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'company_vendor',
            'vendor_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Company/Module/Model/Resource/Vendor/Collection.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\Resource\Vendor;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Company\Module\Model\Vendor',
            'Company\Module\Model\Resource\Vendor'
        );
    }
}
```

Company/Module/Block/VendorList.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class VendorList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $vendorFactory;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                                \Company\Module\Model\VendorFactory $vendorFactory,
                                array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->vendorFactory = $vendorFactory;
    }

    public function getVendors() {
        return  $this->vendorFactory->create()->getCollection()->getItems(); //fails on getCollection()
    }
```

This is the error I get:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Model collection resource name is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had _constructor() instead of _construct()

```
namespace Company\Module\Model;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Resource\Vendor');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following change.

Company/Module/Model/Vendor.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
    protected function _constructor() {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor');
    }
}
```

Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Vendor.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('company_vendor','vendor_id');
    }
}
```

Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Vendor/Collection.php

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Vendor','Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try to caching magento and then check.